# Issues with Javascript countdown

Tags: javascript, countdown

Well I'm trying to recreate the countdown for each of these challenges seen here:
http://www.bungie.net/stats/reach/globalchallenges.aspx

The problem is if you compare [my countdown](http://www.halogamertags.com/test/cd.php) with the [original countdown](http://www.bungie.net/stats/reach/globalchallenges.aspx) there is about a 10-14 second difference, I just don't understand why? Thanks!

I'm using the source from their [mobile page](http://www.bungie.net/mobile/GlobalChallenges.aspx)(view source) to get the expiration times.

```
<span id="wExpSeconds" title="1304330400000"></span>
<span id="dExpMilliseconds" title="1303984800000"></span>
```

Here is the source code of my countdown page:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <style type="text/css">
        .stat{ font: 14px/18px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#bbb; }
        .seconds{ color:#ff5f3c; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="countDownDiv"></div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
        function countDown(id, end, cur){
            this.container = document.getElementById(id);
            this.endDate = new Date(end);
            this.curDate = new Date(cur);


            var context = this;

            var formatResults = function(day, hour, minute, second){
            var displayString = [
                '<span class="stat">',day,'d </span>',
                '<span class="stat">',hour,'h </span>',
                '<span class="stat">',minute,'m </span>',
                '<span class="stat seconds">',second,'s</span>'
            ];
            return displayString.join("");
            }

            var update = function(){
                context.curDate.setSeconds(context.curDate.getSeconds()+1);

                var timediff = (context.endDate-context.curDate)/1000; 

                // Check if timer expired:
                if (timediff<0){ 
                    return context.container.innerHTML = formatResults(0,0,0,0);
                }

                var oneMinute=60; //minute unit in seconds
                var oneHour=60*60; //hour unit in seconds
                var oneDay=60*60*24; //day unit in seconds

                var dayfield=Math.floor(timediff/oneDay);
                var hourfield=Math.floor((timediff-dayfield*oneDay)/oneHour);
                var minutefield=Math.floor((timediff-dayfield*oneDay-hourfield*oneHour)/oneMinute);
                var secondfield=Math.floor((timediff-dayfield*oneDay-hourfield*oneHour-minutefield*oneMinute));

                context.container.innerHTML = formatResults(dayfield, hourfield, minutefield, secondfield);

                // Call recursively
                setTimeout(update, 1000);
            };

            // Call the recursive loop
            update();
            }

        countDown("countDownDiv",1304330400000, new Date().getTime());
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Mine only shows a 6 second difference

Comment: JavaScript timers are unreliable due to the fact that they are executed in one thread: http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/. Not sure if this is your problem, but good to know if you expect a timer to execute *exactly*.

Comment: very odd i see exact match on the times

Comment: Well after doing some comparisons between FF and IE8. I see if i stay in the same browser the timers are the same but there is about 10 seconds difference between IE and FF.

Comment: sorry my bad IE there is about 6 seconds difference. I also want to point out the timer on that site does not keep up its wrong lol Open up your clock and watch the seconds tick away you will see its not ticking at the same time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    function countDown(id, end, cur){
        this.container = document.getElementById(id);
        this.endDate = new Date(end);
        this.curDate = new Date(cur);
```

Since the function is not called as a method of any object, nor with `call()` or `apply()`, its this keyword will reference the global object. So the above effectively creates global variables for container, endDate and curDate.

```
        var context = this;
```

Please write out 1,000 times: **the this keyword is not context** (nor does it have anything to do with scope).

```
         ...
         context.curDate.setSeconds(context.curDate.getSeconds()+1);
```

As already discussed, the variable "context" is a reference to the global object, it is set by how you call the function. So you are accessing global variables here.

```
         ...
         // Call recursively
         setTimeout(update, 1000);
```

Here is your problem. That will call update in **about** 1 second. The longer your counter runs, the more inaccurate it will become (it will always drift later).

You should get a new date object each time, look at the ms, then call the next timeout just after the next full second (give it about 30 to 50ms to make sure it's just after and not before). That way your counter will never be out by much and even if it is, it will correct itself each time it is called.

And make sure you calculate the full count down each time, so if there is a lag of a few seconds you catch up again.

Comment: You have got to stop it with this "`this` is not context" argument or explain what you mean better. The word "context" has a general meaning in the English language, one that clearly applies here. It's the word used in the MDC docs and by JavaScript developers generally. You're confusing people unnecessarily.

Comment: They're confused. ECMAScript has an *execution context*, the *this* keyword is one identifier in that context amongst potentially hundreds or thousands of other variables and parameters on the activation object and scope chain that, all together, might be called "context". To single out `this` as somehow representing the context doesn't make sense. Discuss in [clj](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.javascript/topics?gvc=2) or [jsMentors](http://groups.google.com/group/jsmentors/topics) if you wish.